# register-true in multicols environment

Tags: multicol, grid-typesetting

I have a `multicols*` environment with sections and subsections and list environments and I want the text "registertrue", i.e. the lines are all on the same level ACROSS the columns.(If you were to extend the baseline of a line in a column to the left or right, it would be on the exact same level as the baseline of the line in the other column). 
Not only do the sections mess up the line spacing, floating pictures (inside a single column) or list environments do it, too.
The parskip is set to 0pt.

Comment: TeX really doesn't support grid typesetting very much although you can do things in simple cases. You can see Frank's TUG2013 talk on the subject here (which also has a link to the slides) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcY1zLJNqX0&feature=autoshare